# Bijective function example

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have set $A = \{0,1/2,-1/2,1,-1\}$ and this set is countable, with a bijective function of

$$ f(n) = \begin{cases}
-4n & n<0 \mathrm{\ or\ } n=0 \\
4n-1 & n>0
\end{cases} $$

Set $A$ is a subset of the set which contains all rational numbers. Can I say since set $A$ is countable then $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable?

Comment: This is unreadable.

Comment: Huh? $A$ consists of $4$ elements? Or do you mean $A=\left\{\frac{n}2:n\in\mathbb Z\right\}$. Then surely your map is not bijective onto $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: I've made an edit to improve the math formatting, pending approval. If mine or someone else's is applied, please check to make sure it preserves the intent. You can also click on "edit" to see how it was done.

Comment: Yes sorry I wanted it to be an infinite set.

Comment: Which infinite set do you want it to be? It looks like your function enumerates $$\{0, -4, -8, -12,-16, \ldots\}\cup\{3, 7, 11, 15, 19, \ldots\}$$

Answer (score 3):

No. By that argument, *every* set that contains $A$ is countable too. However, $A\subset\Bbb R$, but $\Bbb R$ is *not* countable.